# ¿Por qué no me muestra los decimales de la variable float?

Tags: c++, funciones, float

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de calcular la media de unos números que da el usuario (siempre que no sea 0) con funciones, pero cuando imprimo la 'm' al final, que representa que es la media ya que divide todos los números entre el contador de veces que ha dado nçumeros el usuario, no da los decimales, simplemente el numero entero. Os dejo el código para que se vea mejor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Array[10];
void mitjana(float m, int st, int cont);
int sumatotal = 0;
int contador = 0;
float mitja;

int main()
{
    for (int k=0; k<10; k++)
    {
        cout<<"Introdueix valor: "; cin >> Array[k];
    }
    mitjana(mitja, sumatotal, contador);
    return(0);
}

void mitjana(float m, int st, int cont)
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (Array[i] != 0)
        {
            st = st + Array[i];
            cont++;
        }
    }
    m = st / cont;
    cout<<m<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema, es que a pesar de que m sea de tipo float, st y cont son de tipo int y por tanto, la división devolverá un entero.
Para obtener los números como decimales, en la propia división podrías hacer un cast:

```
m = float(st) / float(cont);
```